# How to get the country code and national phone number after parsing using the phonenumbers package?

Tags: python, package, phone-number

I'm making an application to clean cellphone number. I'm using the phonenumbers package. So I used     `phonenumbers.parse(Cell No, Country Initials)`
and on console it looks like this:

Country Code: ### National Number: ###

I was planning to just delete some text to get the area code and national number but I remembered that the area code and national number character length is different in other countries.

Is there a way to get just the area code and national numbers seperatly

Comment: Can you share your complete function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phonenumbers.parse` returns a `PhoneNumber` object.
After `y = phonenumbers.parse("020 8366 1177", "GB")`, you can access the attributes by e.g. `y.country_code` or set them by `y.country_code = 49` etc.

Extraction of the area code is a bit tricky as not all countries have the concept of an area code. See [this code snippet](https://github.com/uberbruns/PhoneNumbers/blob/master/Python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L547) of how to correctly get the area code and national subscriber number separately.